# How do I know when a NOMAD GFS Grib2 file is ready for download

Tags: grib-2

The NOMAD GFS system creates files on a 4 times a day cycle.

The file naming specification is:

```
cc is the model cycle runtime (i.e. 00, 06, 12, 18) 
xxx is the forecast hour of product from 00 - 384
YYYYMMDD is the Year, Month and Day
```

'cc' is stated as the cycle run time, so it is reasonable to assume that that is the time the processing begins.

How do I know what time the cycle actually is finished so that the grib2 files can be downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the timing is not specified, so you'd need to poll. As an indication, you can see the dates for the last few cycles at http://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/data/gfs-avn-hi/201310/

I'm not convinced that the start time is exactly 0000, 0600, etc. I think of it as "the data for that cycle".